block bootstrap implementation for `gls` from `nlme`
I have several datasets of timeseries data (days) with an experimental intervention on some days, where some of the datasets cover multiple sites. I also have matching day-level and site-level covariates.
To analyse these data in a mixed effects way (random across sites) I can use lme from nlme, and in a fixed effects way (sites considered only as themselves, or single-site) I can use gls. Because I assume serial correlation of within-site errors, I use the correlation parameter of both functions.
I'm not too sure about normality though, which is why I looked into bootstrap approaches. The lmeresampler package implements the "random effect block bootstrap" method (Chambers & Chandra 2013) for lme, but there is no corresponding "fixed effect block bootstrap" (which I assume would simply be per-group block bootstrap) for gls.
My question: Is there an R package which does for gls what lmeresampler does for lme?
I searched a lot, but didn't find anything which seemed fitting. E.g. there is Gls from rms which has built-in bootstrapping, but the documentation does not explain whether it can deal with serial correlations. And there is tsboot from the boot package, but it is designed for pure timeseries models, not errors in a linear model. I could probably put something together myself but I don't want to (a) reinvent the wheel and (b) make a mistake.
Alternatively I would also interested in other approaches than (random effect) block bootstrap, which can be uniformly applied to lme and gls fits.
Though this question is mainly about software / implementation, I believe it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer and is therefore (borderline) on-topic. Please direct me elsewhere if that's not the case.

Toy example data, gv is the "site" variable:
set.seed(123)
time <- 0 : 9
data0 <- data.frame(time) |>
    mutate(
        iv = as.numeric(time >= 5),
        dv = iv + as.vector(arima.sim(n = 10, list(ar = c(0.5)))),
        gv = 0
    )
data1 <- data.frame(time) |>
    mutate(
        iv = as.numeric(time < 5),
        dv = 2 * iv + as.vector(arima.sim(n = 10, list(ar = c(0.5)))),
        gv = 1
    )
data <- bind_rows(data0, data1)

Mixed effects analysis and random effect block bootstrap:
lme_data <- lme(
    fixed = dv ~ 1 + iv,
    random = ~ 1 | gv,
    correlation = corAR1(form = ~ time | gv),
    data = data
)
boot_lme_data <- reb_bootstrap(
    lme_data,
    .f = extract_parameters,
    B = 1000,
    reb_type = 1
)
confint(boot_lme_data, type = "perc")

Fixed effects analysis, but no block bootstrap:
gls_data <- gls(
    model = dv ~ 1 + iv + gv,
    correlation = corAR1(form = ~ time | gv),
    data = data
)
boot_gls_data <- # ???

